# Nginx expires headers for image in location

Tags: nginx

I try to set expires headers for jpg and png in my folder, but not for files in subfolders.Can somebody help me with this?

I have folder /assets where Rails store precompiled assets. But in this folder I also have many subfolders for users image - and for files in this subfolders I don't want to set expiration date.

So, location should be for all files in folder /public/assets/ , but not for files in dynamic created subfolders in /public/assets/

```
location /assets/(jpg|png){ #but not for files in subfolders for /assets/


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
location /assets/([^/]+)\.(png|jpg){

}
```

Cheers